# Testing Batch apex code with two batches

Tags: apex, batch, unit-test

i am trying to test a trigger my trigger code is

```
trigger PostFeedsToTimeLine on FeedItem (after insert) {
Map<String,String> contentMap = new Map<String,String>{'Object' =>'FeedItem','Content' =>'Body'};
if(Trigger.new.size() > 5){
BatchPublishTimeLine publishBatch = new BatchPublishTimeLine(Trigger.new,contentMap);
Database.executeBatch(publishBatch,5);
}
else GMirrorUtil.createTimeLine(Trigger.new, contentMap);
}
```

batch will always get created if size is greater than 5 but when size is greater than 5 two batch will get executed what to do.in batch i am calling GMirrorUtil.createTimeLine which is making two callouts thats why this 5 limit .what to do in this case ?? because maximum 5 batch can be queued thats why if possible i try to make it without batch but in cases when more than 5 then i execute it using Batch.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet here is to just change the logic by using `Test.IsRunningTest()`. If that's `true` then pass in a new list with just one entry to the batch itself:

```
BatchPublishTimeLine publishBatch = new BatchPublishTimeLine(Test.IsRunningTest() ? new List<FeedItem>{Trigger.new[0]} : Trigger.new),contentMap);
```

I'm using the ternary if operator so that it's still one line of code and as such will prevent a missed line of coverage.